# Finding $m$ such that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}{\sin(mx)\cot\frac{x}{\sqrt{3}}} = 2$

Tags: limits

> I am given that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\sin(mx)\cot\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{3}}\right) = 2$$ and invited to solve for $m$.

My approach is like this. Re arrange the limit like so:

$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}{\sin(mx) \cos(\frac{x}{\sqrt{3}})} = 2\times \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}{\sin(\frac{x}{\sqrt{3}})}
\\
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}{\sin(mx) \cos(\frac{x}{\sqrt{3}})} = 0
\\
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}{\sin(mx)} = 0
$$

My conclusion is that the value of $m$ is immaterial: the limit will go to zero anyway.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Is it cot or cos

Comment: @NamburuKarthik the question says cotangent. I expanded it into cos/sin.

Comment: If it is cot it is easy just bring it in denominator as tan and open above sin as m and bottom tan as x/root3 and it is root3*m=2 so m=2/root3

Comment: In ur process the mistake is at bringing sin(x/root3) to that side then both sides the limit is zero and u can’t conclude next

Comment: @NamburuKarthik it would be nice if you could.

Comment: Ok..............

Comment: It's fine. By the way, this is not Quora, don't beg for reputation in the comments. You may get banned. Use comments only for details about the question or to add suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've shown is that $\lim_{x\to0} \sin(mx)=0$ for every $m$, which is true. However, this tells you nothing about the limit $$\lim_{x\to0} \sin(mx)\cot(x/\sqrt 3),$$ which is an indeterminate form $0\cdot\infty$. You still have the job of determining what $m$ needs to be in order to resolve the indeterminate form into the value $2$. To do that, you should ignore the future result $2$ and simply work out the indeterminate form:
$$
\lim_{x\to0} \sin(mx)\cot(x/\sqrt 3)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(mx)\cos (x/\sqrt 3)}{\sin(x/\sqrt 3)}\tag1
$$
The RHS of (1) now has the form $\frac 00$, which you can evaluate with L'Hopital's rule. The answer will depend on $m$.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Just bringing cot(x/root3) to denominator and applying limit

I hope this helps u

Comment: You should use math formatting instead of pictures.

Comment: Ok.............

Answer (score 1):

It is immediate that if you choose $m=\dfrac1{\sqrt 3}$, the expression simplifies to $\cos\dfrac x{\sqrt 3}\to1$ and this contradicts your thinking that the limit is always $0$.

---

Now, think that

$$\sin\frac{2x}{\sqrt3}=2\sin\frac{x}{\sqrt3}\cos\frac{x}{\sqrt3}.$$